# Duplicate 404 Code in many Controllers: Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have following code.

```
private function GetCountry($CountryID) {
    $Country = \App\Models\CountryModel
                ::where('CountryID', $CountryID)
                ->where('IsPredefined', false)
                ->first();
    if($Country == null) {
        \App::abort(404);
        return;
    }
    return $Country;
}
```

If condition is added to make sure if user is trying a query string, whose associated record is not present in the database. In case I remove the if condition check, I get the below error in Blade.

> Trying to get property of non-object

Same function is defined with different model according to their Controller.

Question: Can I reduce the code? I want to keep 404 error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use [firstOrFail()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent) which will do that check for you

> if no result is found, a Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException will be thrown
>
> If the exception is not caught, a 404 HTTP response is automatically sent back to the user, so it is not necessary to write explicit checks to return 404 responses when using these methods: